# Do I need to collect swingWorker threads when they are done?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I am using a GUI to call swing worker threads.

After they finish and excute the method `done()`, I am printing `Thread.activeCount()`. I get a number which indicates the threads are still active.

Do I need to collect them somehow when they are done?

Comment: What do you mean by collecting them? Garbage collecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot manually destroy the threads created by `SwingWorker` instances. These threads run in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` which is not exposed.

```
public final void execute() {
    getWorkersExecutorService().execute(this);
}

private static synchronized ExecutorService getWorkersExecutorService()
```

You'll have to wait for the timeout. Each thread that's generated has a time-out of 10 minutes.

```
executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(MAX_WORKER_THREADS, MAX_WORKER_THREADS, 10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), threadFactory);
```

These threads are daemon, so the program will still shutdown if they're the last threads in your program.

Comment: so what you are saying is that I can't terminate them manually or collect them somehow. I just need to wait until they're finished or get detroyed by the time out?  what happens if they don't finish by 10 minutes? will they get destroyed before they get to the done() function?   Another question, is there a way to tell if a thread is still active and haven't excuted done() method?

Comment: @David8988 Yes, they weren't meant to be terminated manually, they die out on their own. The 10 minutes is a timeout: if the thread isn't re-used within that timeframe, it's terminated. A worker thread will not terminate while being used. You are too focused on the thread aspect, rather the behavior you actually want. You shouldn't need to dig into what threads are active. What you want is to see if a task is still running/processing. You should be extending SwingWorker to add the functionality you need.

Comment: Exactly. I need to know if a task is still running/processing. Is there a way to know that using the SwingWorker Thread instance?

Comment: @David8988 Theres nothing built-in for that. It's technically possible by filtering all threads, but would require some pretty nasty management. You really should extend it if the default behavior doesn't satisfy your needs. Could create a `boolean running` that the worker sets to true/false, then expose an `boolean isRunning()` method so others can determine whether it's finished. Or you could use a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) which `done()` calls when the task is finished. Show a concrete example, I could give a concrete answer with example.

Comment: "*if the thread isn't re-used within that timeframe, it's terminated*" `SwingWorker` is not built to be re-used.

Comment: @David8988 "*I need to know if a task is still running/processing. Is there a way to know that using the SwingWorker Thread instance?*" Use [`isDone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#isDone--).

Comment: @user1803551 I'm talking about the threads in the pool, which are reused for different SwingWorkers. Props on `isDone()`